# I forgot my old email for my minecraft account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had forgotten my old email and have tried every possible thing I could think of but I still can't get through my old account. I don't have a Mojang acccount and still had my old minecraft premium account on since I hadn't migrated to the Mojang account ( Since I couldn't because I had forgotten my old email ) and the minecraft forums aren't helping since it only helps people who have a Mojang account.

I genuinely think that it is impossible to get my old account back and this may be my last hope out there.

Comment: Your only chance is contacting Mojang support, but if you don't know any account details you'll probably have bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

Only Mojang Support can help with lost accounts. You would need the username of the account and maybe the password. That would really be the only way to get your account back.